# Read excel dates and convert them to individual strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

I recently started using python.
I have a series of dates in excel

01-05-2021

02-05-2021

.
.

29-05-2021

Now, I want to load this column and convert it into individual strings based on rows. So i can extract the day, month and year separately for each dates

Can someone help me how to do that??

Comment: Please, consider providing a desired output, and also, what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Amirhossein Kiani
I was looking to acquire an array with different dates, from which the year, month and date can be extracted seperately. For further work that i am planning.

Comment: @k33da_the_bug

I didn't know about this solution. Let it try it first.

Comment: @k33da_the_bug
Hey, the solution worked just well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

# let's imagine your date column name is "date"

df["day"] = df["date"].apply(lambda elem:elem.split("-")[0])
df["month"] = df["date"].apply(lambda elem:elem.split("-")[1])
df["year"] = df["date"].apply(lambda elem:elem.split("-")[2])
```

Comment: Hey
I tried the approach, but i keep getting this error "'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'". 
What to do in this??

Comment: Hey, the solution worked just well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
```

str_time = 01-05-2021
time_convert = datetime.strptime(str_time, '%d-%m-%Y')

```
print (time_convert, time_convert.day, time_convert.month, time_convert.year)
```

in your case, make the convert in looping for each data you got from the excel file

Comment: I tried the "strptime" method before. But the input isn't in a "string" format. Instead it is "timestamp", so the dates don't get converted. How to do in that case?

Comment: Put here your code, maybe i can help.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you for the offer though